# Nazir and Tefillin

Tags: tefilin, hair, nozir, chatzitzah

According to the opinions that state that long hair is considered a chatzitza for tefillin, how would a nazir, who doesn't cut his hair, be able to wear tefillin properly?

Comment: https://www.yeshiva.org.il/ask/94582 שמצינו אחרונים שמתירים לגדל שיער ארוך...כי הם הביאו ראיות שמותר, לדוג’ מנזיר. They bring this as a kasha on those opinions. Which is basically your question, how did they understand Nazir.

Comment: Isnt the main reason it would be a chatiztza is if  the hair is folded ontop. If the hair is in place naturally how can that be a chatiztza

Comment: If they physically can't wear it they're exempt, like an amputee or someone with a cast on. What's your question? Do you have any reason to think all Nezirim did wear Tefillin?

Comment: @DoubleAA the picture books draw Shmuel with long hair and tefillin (going with the opinion he was a Nazir).

Comment: @robev Picture books draw many things which are not always true.